# Java or Python regexp search of large list of words

Tags: regex, python-3.x, java-8

I have an list of "Nw" English words that I would like to search using "Ne" different regexp's.  Nw is several hundred thousand entries, and Ne is several hundred.  The regexp's allow only individual character substitution, that is, the regexp's contain only "word characters" (`\w`) or `?`'s (more than one is possible).  I would like to find all matching words for each regexp.

I *don't* want to do this with something like the following:

```
for regexp in regexp_list:
    for word in word_list:
        found_list = re.findall( regexp, word )
        ...do something with found_list...
```

Given the problem I'm working on, I *do* need to explicitly loop over the `regexp_list`, but I'd like to avoid the iteration over the much larger `word_list`.  Is there some regexp magic that will allow me to do this, something like:

```
for regexp in regexp_list:
    found_list = re.findall_in_word_list( regexp, word_list )
```

I've been thinking about using a suffix tree to hold the word list, and use a special version of lookup that handles the `?`'s d(necessitating a depth-first search of the suffix tree), but I'd prefer to use a pre-existing solution if it's available.

My solution to the problem can use either Java 8 or Python 3 (or NLP libraries in either language, if appropriate).

Answer (score 1):

If it's speed you are after it's going to be tough to beat running a set of prepared regex expressions against each word in your master list.  Even if you come up with a super-statement like you suggest, it will still have to iterate over the master list, it will just do it internally.

In Python an "internal" command could be significant over looping (Python is relatively slow when it's doing it's own looping, but many routines are coded in C/Assembly), but iterating in Java wouldn't add a significant overhead (Java is nearly as fast as C for that type of operation, and fairly easy to thread).

I suppose for the "Easy" mode I'd try running the double loop as a Java stream operation -- let the stream multi-thread and see what happens.

A harder mode might be to eliminate classes of words so you don't have to look at the whole word for each match.  For instance if you pulled all your matches that could possibly match words beginning with "a" then you wouldn't have to check words that don't start with "a" against this group.  There could be a lot of tricks here, but it would be a lot of code, it would get complex really fast and it would probably not offer much benefit.

Comment: I'll try @dawg's suggestion, doing it in Java for the reason Bill K explains.   However, I'm still concerned about the inner loop (over words):   Seems like there's no avoiding the O(Nw) factor using the regexp approach, either way.  I'm still going to consider the suffix tree because the complexity should be *something* like O(Lw*62^N?) where Lw is the average length of a word in the list, N? is the number of ?'s in the regexp, and 62 is the number of \w chars.  Of course, the code is more complex (!)

Comment: One possibility--you might have a group of regex expressions that starts with "Unknown" then one for each other letter.  You then only apply "Unknown" and one of the letters to each word as it passes by.  Also, consider the threaded stream solution--it should give you a significant boost without hurting complexity at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet might be taking:

```
for regexp in regexp_list:
    for word in word_list:
        found_list = re.findall( regexp, word )
        ...do something with found_list...
```

and instead do:

```
string_of_list='uniq_delimiter_character_or_sequence'.join(word_list)
for regexp in regexp_list:
    found_list = re.findall( regexp, string_of_list )
        ...do something with found_list...
```

That obviously does not work if `word_list` can contain every character in existence, but that is pretty rare.

Since you have stated it is only word character regex's and a list of words, your join might be as simple as tab or new line delimited.